# jquery UI Slider bound to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

```
<p>Cost: $<span id="hddValue"></span></p>
<p>Cost2: $<span id="hddValue2"></span></p>

<select id="hdd">
  <option>1000</option>
  <option>2000</option>
  <option>3000</option>
  <option>4000</option>
  <option>5000</option>
</select>

<select id="hdd2">
  <option>1700</option>
  <option>500</option>
  <option>3700</option>
  <option>4300</option>
  <option>5070</option>
</select>

$(function () {
            var select = $('#hdd');
            var slider = $("<div id='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
                min: 1,
                max: 5,
                range: "true",
                value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
              $("#hddValue").text($('#hdd option:selected').text());
             $("#hddValue2").text($('#hdd2 option:selected').text());
                }
            });
        //show start value
        $( "#hddValue" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
        $( "#hddValue2" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
        });
```

Can anyone please help me with this js script? What i want to do is when I move the slider i want each selected values to show up on the page as seen on two option values "hdd" and "hdd2".

right now what happens is when i move the slider only #hdd changes and when i add #hdd2 in the javascript, the hdd2 html view just freezes to the first option and doesn't change.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update method only updates both selects but with the value of the first one.
Havent tried it but it should look something like this, btw. having mutliple elements with the same id (your sliders) is invalid and breaks older browsers.

```
<p>Cost: $<span class="hddvalue"></span></p>
<p>Cost2: $<span class="hddvalue"></span></p>

<select id="hdd">
  <option>1000</option>
  <option>2000</option>
  <option>3000</option>
  <option>4000</option>
  <option>5000</option>
</select>

<select id="hdd2">
  <option>1700</option>
  <option>500</option>
  <option>3700</option>
  <option>4300</option>
  <option>5070</option>
</select>

$(function () {
            var
                $selects = $('#hdd,#hdd2'),
                $values = $('.hddvalue')
            ;
            $selects.each(function (i) {
                var sel = this;
                $("<div class='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
                    min: 1,
                    max: 5,
                    range: "true",
                    value: sel.selectedIndex + 1,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        sel.selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
                       $values.eq(i).text(jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text());
                    }
                });
            });

        //show start value
        $values.eq(0).html(  $('.slider').eq(0).slider('value') );
        $values.eq(1).html(  $('.slider').eq(1).slider('value') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
            var
                $selects = $('#hdd,#hdd2'),
                $values = $('.hddvalue');
            $selects.each(function (i) {
                var sel = this;
                $("<div class='slider'></div>").insertAfter(sel).slider({
                    min: 1,
                    max: 5,
                    range: "true",
                    value: sel.selectedIndex + 1,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        sel.selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
                       $values.eq(i).text(jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text());
                    }
                });
            });

        //show start value
        $values.eq(0).html(  $('.slider').eq(0).slider('value') );
        $values.eq(1).html(  $('.slider').eq(1).slider('value') );
});
```